# Automatically restarting process in the X server

Tags: linux, scripting, xorg, kubuntu

I would like to know how to have a process that starts with the X server and automatically restarts when it stops running. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 with a KDE 4.13.3 desktop.

I am running the program 'touchegg' to support multitouch gestures.I currently have the program setup to run automatically using the autostart section of KDE's control panel. However the process occasionally stops working, often after hibernation and I would like it to automatically restart if this happens. It seems like it should be fairly straight forward but all the information I can find about automatically restarting processes is for processes that run at boot time rather than after Xorg starts.

Comment: Does "stops working" mean it hangs (and you need to kill it) or that it exits (and you just need to start it again)?

Comment: It hangs. I have solved it by launching it as a normal user in the power management scripts.